# Remove/Exclude tags from extracted texts scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

After using scrapy and CSS selector, I tried scraping a paragraph from HTML. The paragraph contained hyperlinks with tags `<a ....>text</a>`. If I used `response.css("p::text").get()` then the hyperlink was not present in my text. If I directly used this code If I used `response.css("p").get()` then I would get text containing the `<a>` tag, which I am unable to remove using regex. I want to know the code for getting text irrespective of the tags. For eg.

> We should note that Dr. Anthony Fauci, the director of the National Institute of Allergy and InfectiousDiseases, praised the administration’s restrictions on travel. On Feb. 29, 2020, he *<a href="https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-vice-president-pence-members-coronavirus-task-force-press-conference-2/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">said</a>*: "We prevented travel from China to the United States. If we had not done that, we would have had many, many more cases right here that we would have to be dealing with."

As you could see during text extraction I want to remove or exclude the tags(as Italicized above) and get the following text using CSS selector using scrapy

> We should note that Dr. Anthony Fauci, the director of the National Institute of Allergy and InfectiousDiseases, praised the administration’s restrictions on travel. On Feb. 29, 2020, he said: "We prevented travel from China to the United States. If we had not done that, we would have had many, many more cases right here that we would have to be dealing with."

Comment: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
remove_tags(my_text)  # print this
```